# grep entire text based on key words

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

i have a file consists of oracle select statements as given below.

```
select count(*) into v_cnt from table;
select
  max(num) into v_max 
from table2;
select numm from table3;
```

output is given below -

```
select count(*) into v_cnt from table;
select
  max(num) into v_max 
from table2;
```

i need help on grepping the select statements(from select keyword till semicolon) which has into key word. select statements may goes n number of rows. begining of line is select. ending of line is semicolon. in between these keywords if we have into text. then we need to capture the whole line. i am trying grep/awk statement. but i am not getting exaclty. multiple line select statements are breaking. Any ideas/suggestions from your end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the string `into` can appear anywhere else in your input such that you do NOT want the select statement printed when `into` appears there then you should include those cases in your sample input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -0x3b -ne 'print if /\binto\b/'
```

- `-0x3b` sets the record separator to character `x3b`, i.e. `;`
- `-n` reads the input record by record, running the code for each
- `\b` matches a word boundary, so all records containing "into" that's not part of a longer word should be printed

If there are some commands that don't start with `select` and you want to skip them, change the condition to `if /^select\b/m && /\binto\b/` (which can be incorporated into a single regex `if /^select\b.*\binto\b/ms`). To make the regexes case insensitive, add the `/i` modifier: `/^select\b/mi`.

Answer (score 0):

awk: issel remembers whether select lacked a ;:

```
{
        if (issel = (issel || $0 ~ /select/)) print $0;

        issel = !( $0 ~ /;/)
}
```

Comment: `$0 ~ /select/` = `/select/` and `!( $0 ~ /;/)` = `!/;/` and `print $0;
` = `print` and `{if (issel = (issel || $0 ~ /select/)) print $0;}` = `issel = (issel || /select/)` so the whole scrtipt could be reduced to `issel=(issel || /select/); {issel=!/;/}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tr '\n' '~' < <Input file> | sed 's#;#\n#g' |  grep -i 'select.*into.*' | tr '~' '\n'
```

Demo:

```
$cat file.txt 
select count(*) into v_cnt from table;
select
  max(num) into v_max 
from table2;
select numm from table3;
$tr '\n' '~' < file.txt | sed 's#;#\n#g' |  grep -i 'select.*into.*' | tr '~' '\n'
select count(*) into v_cnt from table

select
  max(num) into v_max 
from table2
$
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=";\n"} /into/' file
select count(*) into v_cnt from table;
select
  max(num) into v_max
from table2;
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' '/into/{sub(/^\n/,""); print}' file
select count(*) into v_cnt from table;
select
  max(num) into v_max
from table2;
```